# Exact sequence and short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, finite-groups, exact-sequence

In group theory, a sequence
$$
G_0\stackrel{f_1}{\longrightarrow} G_1 \stackrel{f_2}{\longrightarrow} G_2 \stackrel{f_3}{\longrightarrow}\; . . .\, \stackrel{f_n}{\longrightarrow} G_n
$$
of groups and homomorphisms is called **exact** if the image of each homomorphism is the kernel of the subsequent one:
$$
\operatorname{Im}f_i=\,\operatorname{Ker}f_i\quad,\qquad\mbox{for}\quad\mbox 1\leq i < n\;.
$$
Also see this picture borrowed from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#/media/File:Illustration_of_an_Exact_Sequence_of_Groups.svg). (Here the sequence is set infinite in both directions, though.)

[image]

If some morphism $f_{i+1}$ in this figure is a monomorphism, then its Ker is $e_i$.

After this figure, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) provides three examples:

Example (a).
In $\,e_0 \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow Y\,$, $\;$the image of $\,e_{\textstyle{_0}}$ is $\,e_{\textstyle{_X}}\,$, $\;$wherefore $\, X \longrightarrow Y\, $ is a monomorphism.

QUESTION:
What is the meaning of the left arrow, $\,e_{\textstyle{_0}} \longrightarrow X\,$?
I thought, there should be some initial group $G_0$ on the left (so we would get $\,G_0 \longrightarrow X\,$).
Or is it implied that this $G_0$ is trivial, i.e., consists of the neutral element $e_{\textstyle{_0}}$ solely?

Example (b).
In $\,X \longrightarrow Y \longrightarrow e\,$, $\;$the kernel of the rightmost map is $Y$. $\;$Hence the image of the map $X\longrightarrow Y$ is all of $Y$. So this is an epimorphism.

Example (c) is a combination of the former and latter ones.
The sequence $0 \longrightarrow X \longrightarrow Y \longrightarrow 0\,$ is exact iff the map $X \longrightarrow Y$ is both a monomorphism and epimorphism (i.e., is an isomorphism).

Wikipedia also defined a **short exact sequence** as
$$
0\longrightarrow A \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} C \longrightarrow 0
$$
where  $f$ is a monomorphism and $g$ is an epimorphism.
I guess, "$0$" on the left is the neutral element $\,e_{\textstyle{_0}}$ of the initial group, while "$0$" on the right is the neutral element $e$ of the final group -- is that right?

Based on Example (b) above, $g$ is epimorphic (surjective) in this short exact sequence.
Based on Example (a), $f$ is monomorphic (injective), assuming that $\,e_{\textstyle{_0}}$ (denoted with "$0$" on the left) is mapped to $\,e_{\textstyle{_A}}$.
But then I again fail to grasp the meaning of the leftmost arrow: why is the preimage of $A$ just a neutral element of the initial group? And why is it mapped exactly to the neutral element of $A$? I am missing something big here.

Comment: Please don't use images for mathematical formulas. [See here for why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: $e$ or $0$ means the trivial group. In this case there is only one option to define a homomorphism, and so we don't write it above the arrow.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Understood. Typed the formulae.

Comment: @Mark Is it implied that, if the initial group is trivial, then it must be mapped to the neutral element of the subsequent group?

Comment: @Michael_1812 Yes, because a group homomorphism always maps identity to identity. If $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism then $f(e_G)=f(e_Ge_G)=f(e_G)f(e_G)$. Multiply by the inverse of $f(e_G)$ in $H$ to get $f(e_G)=e_H$.

Comment: @Mark OK, thank you. Now I got this: the only possibility for $e_0$ is to be mapped to $e_X\,$

Comment: @Michael_1812 Yes, this is the only option. From the comment above it follows that if you map $e_0$ to anything else, it will not be a homomorphism.

Comment: @Mark I again wish to thank you. If you find a minute to shape your comment into a full answer, it will be my pleasure to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: @Michael_1812 Ok, I added an answer.

Comment: @Mark One more kind request, if I may. Since $f$ is a monomorphism, A is a subgroup of B. Why is it a *normal* subgroup? Is this simply the kernel is always normal?

Comment: @Michael_1812 Yes, here the image of $f$ is equal to the kernel of $g$, and a kernel is always a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the symbols $e_0, e, 0$ all mean the trivial group. Since a group homomorphism must map identity to identity, in this case there is only one possible homomorphism $e_0\to X$, and so we don't write it above the arrow.